# how to create a MySql query to display running balance from credit and debit where multiple customers have indivdual balances

Tags: mysql, view, calculation, bank

I have a table as with the structure below:

[image]

The Table is a simple credit and debit table for different customers **( each customer has his own ID)**.

Transactions take place on different dates. Each transaction has its own ID which is chronologically generated.

A view must be created as showing the running balance of each customer. The view gives the list chronologically arranged.

The list items are

1. Transaction:

- ID
- Customer_ID
- Date
- Credit
- Debit and
- Balance (Calculated)

I would like to get the query code for solving the above problem.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please consider to include the query that you've tried yet.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? Later versions have windowing functions, so the version affects the answer.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? Later versions have windowing functions, so the version affects the answer.

Comment: The Version of the database is 10.2.22 MariaDB

Comment: CREATE TABLE `ledger` (
  `transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer ID',
  `date` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Transacrion date time',
  `credit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Credit',
  `debit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'debit',
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `credit`) VALUES ('1', '100', '2020-10-10', '100.00');
INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `debit`) VALUES ('2', '100', '2020-10-10', '50.00');
INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `credit`) VALUES ('3', '2000', '2020-10-14', '300.00');
INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `credit`, `debit`) VALUES ('4', '100', '2020-10-14', '0.00', '10.00');

Comment: INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `credit`) VALUES ('5', '50', '2020-10-20', '400.00');
INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `debit`) VALUES ('6', '2000', '2020-10-20', '30.00');
INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `credit`) VALUES ('7', '2000', '2020-10-25', '50.00');
INSERT INTO `db24910`.`ledger` (`transaction_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `debit`) VALUES ('8', '50', '2020-11-10', '300.00');

Comment: I would like to generate the last column, i.e. Balance to be generated completely.The balance for each customer_id is calculated from (credit-debit)+ Balance of the previous record where the customer_id is the same. I am new to SQL and do not know how to create a query giving the list as per the attached picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
  select  transaction_id, customer_id, date, credit, debit,
  abs(sum(ifnull(credit,0)) over (partition by customer_id order by date,credit,transaction_id ) - sum(ifnull(debit,0)) over(partition by customer_id order by date,debit,transaction_id)) as balance
  from ledger
  order by transaction_id;
```